# An interesting function: Plot f[x] != Plot f[y]

Tags: plotting, function-construction, variable-definitions

Let's consider this function

```
f[a_] := x^2 /. FindMinimum[-a x^2 + x^4, {x, 1}][[2]]
```

Why the output of the following two `Plot` are different:

```
Plot[f[y], {y, -3, 3}]
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

Comment: In the second case, you are now evaluating `x^2 /. FindMinimum[-x^3 + x^4, {x, 1}][[2]]`, no? Use `Module[]`: `f[a_] := Module[{x}, x^2 /. FindMinimum[-a x^2 + x^4, {x, 1}][[2]]]`.

Comment: Yes I see; but I expected that in `f[x]` the argument `x` is a free variable; that means that I thought `Plot` doesn't evaluate `f[x]` before than substituting a value; so I thought `Plot` take the value `-3` and print `{-3, f[-3]}` after `-2.999` and print `{-2.999, f[-2.999]}` and so on. But it's not the case. On the other hand, `Plot` cannot evaluate `f[y]` before substituting a value for `y`, as it seems to do in `f[x]`: in this case it cannot evaluate `f[y]`. So how does `Plot` work??

Comment: `Plot` works like this: `Block[{x = 3}, f[x]] // Trace` -- Note that `FindMinimum` effectively blocks the instances of `x` in the definition, but not the parameter `x` in `f[x]` which has already evaluated to `3` nor the `x` in the `x^2` outside of `FindMinimum`, which has also already evaluated to `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs for [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), it effectively uses `Block` to evaluate `f[x]` in a localized environment.  Tracing the evaluation of `f[x]` inside a `Block` reveals what happens:

```
Block[{x = 3}, f[x]] // Trace

{Block[{x = 3}, f[x]],      (* begin evaluation *)
 {x = 3, 3},                (* evaluate first argument *)
 {                          (* begin evaluation of f[x] *)
  {x, 3},                   (*   first evaluate argument x *)
  f[3],                     (*   begin evaluation of f[3] *)
  x^2 /. FindMinimum[-3 x^2 + x^4, {x, 1}][[2]],  (* f[3] replaced by def. of f *)
  {                         (*     begin evaluation of ReplaceAll *)
   {x, 3}, 3^2, 9},         (*       evaluation of x^2 *)
  {                         (*       begin evaluation of FindMinimum *)
   {FindMinimum[-3 x^2 + x^4, {x, 1}],  
    {{{-3, -3}, -3 x^2}, -3 x^2 + x^4},     (* evaluate first argument *)
    {{x} =., {x =.}, {x =., Null}, {Null}}, (*   block x *)
    {-2.2499999999999996`, {x -> 1.2247448715336158`}}, (* FindMinimum result *)
    {                       (*         x has a value: begin evaluation Rule in result *)
     {{x, 3},               (*           first argument *)
      3 -> 1.2247448715336158`,  (*      Rule with value of x *)
      3 -> 1.2247448715336158`}, (*    result of Rule evaluation *)
     {3 -> 1.2247448715336158`}},
    {-2.2499999999999996`, {3 -> 1.2247448715336158`}} (* final result of FindMinimum *)
    },
   {-2.2499999999999996`, {3 -> 1.2247448715336158`}}[[2]], (* evaluate Part *)
   {3 -> 1.2247448715336158`}},  (*   final result of 2nd arg. of ReplaceAll *)
  9 /. {3 -> 1.2247448715336158`}, (* evaluate ReplaceAll with evaluated arguments *)
  9},                       (*     result of ReplaceAll *)
 9}                         (*   result of f[x] *)
```

If one follows closely, one can see that the result of `Plot` will be the graph of `x^2`, except when `x` and `x^2` are identical, that is if `x` is zero or one.  Well, it's really hard to get `Plot` to hit a particular number exactly.  But it's easier with `Table`, which evaluates its argument in a way similar to `Plot`.

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1./2^13, 1./2^13, 1./2^20}], 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1 - 1./2^2, 1 + 1./2^2, 1./2^9}], 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]